# Is there any way to create a node.js application that will remap OSX keypresses?

Tags: node.js, macos

I want to write a `Node.js` application that will remap OSX keys. It will interpret keypresses from OSX, and send back the correct key, which will be received by the application. It should intercept every keypress in any kind of software. Is that possible?

Comment: If I'm not way off base, a keycode is just a number. If you have a lookup table to convert from Mac keycodes to the keys you want, then it should be pretty simple.

Comment: Probably, the logic is simple. I just need to know how to interact with the system properly.